# How do I find the correct range to insert more sections into a UITableView?

Tags: uitableview

I realize that there is a different between a count and index in obj-c.

For this question and my issue to make sense, I will use the following examples to demonstrate.

My _data.count begins at 0.

After viewDidLoad, I fetch and insert sections where _data.count = 10

```
NSIndexSet *set = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, _data.count)];   
[self.tableView insertSections:set
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

This works as expected as I now have sections [0-9]. Later I add to the _data where _data.count = 12. Then I try to do a simple insert like before, but changing the starting index.

```
NSInteger sections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
NSIndexSet *set = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(sections, _data.count)];   
[self.tableView insertSections:set
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

I would, maybe naively, expect this to insert the sections at [10-11]. The sections = 10, but my app crashes with the exception 'attempt to insert section 12 but there are only 12 sections after the update'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not understand how NSRange works. Here is the struct for NSRange.

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
  NSUInteger location;
  NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;
```

I read about NSIndexSet and realized that it provides some helpers which I took advantage of to help figure out how I can correctly solve this.

Using the earlier example, this is what I learned about the ranges of the index set.

```
NSLog(@"first index %ld", (unsigned long)[set firstIndex]);
/* logs 10 */

NSLog(@"last index %ld", (unsigned long)[set lastIndex]); 
/* logs 21 ? what the heck */
```

So with that information, I knew all I had to do was subtract the current section count from the update _data.count.

```
NSInteger sections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
NSIndexSet *set = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(sections, _data.count-sections)];   
[self.tableView insertSections:set
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Now that I understood what was wrong, I need to know how NSRange works. So I read about it and it became obvious why I was getting this error. The first number is the starting point, I.E. location and then the second number is the amount of places to move, I.E. length.